# Why JQuery's .post returns no data?

Tags: jquery, json, mojo, mojolicious

I post JSON request to remote service. Everything is OK, service works fine and it response to me. But I have no data returned from remote service. How to get data from remote json service by JQuery via .post? Why this example returns the data -- ``null':

```
<SCRIPT> 
$(function() {
    $('#zzz').click(function() {
        $('#lak').html('wait...');
        $.post(
  'http://127.0.0.1:3000/test',
  "{\"ipaddr\":\"192.168.132.58\"}",
  function(data) { alert(data); },
  "json"
        )
    });
});
</SCRIPT>
```

But the TCP sniffer shows me that service returns some data:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
X-Powered-By: Mojolicious (Perl)
Date: Thu, 02 Sep 2010 06:17:10 GMT
Content-Length: 37
Server: Mojolicious (Perl)

{"status":"OK","result":"successful"}
```

**Solved:**

```
<SCRIPT> 
$(function() {
    $('#clickme').click(function() {
 $.getJSON('http://domain.tld/test/?foo=bar&callback=?',
 function(jsonp) {
  $('#jsonp-example').html(jsonp.result);
 });
    });
});
</SCRIPT>

<div id="jsonp-example"><a id="clickme" href="javascript:void()">Click me</a></div>
```

And example of Mojolicious JSONP service:

```
# /test/?foo=bar&callback=smth
get '/test' => sub { 
 my $self = shift;

 my $foo  = $self->param('foo') || '';
 my $callback = $self->param('callback') || 'jsonp';
...
 my $json = $self->render(
  json => {
   'status' => 'OK',
   'result' => 'successful'
  }, 
  partial => 1);

 $self->render(data => "$callback($json)", format => 'js');
} => 'test';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'e running into the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which prevents (among other things) an XmlHttpRequest from getting data from a remote domain.  Your POST *will* be successful, but the browser won't allow you to get the response back.

Since you're going to a remote domain, your best shot is to [support JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP), it works in a different way, you can't POST so it'll get a GET, but it will allow you to get data back.  JSONP uses an *entirely* different method of getting the data, basically defining your callback as a name function then creating a `<script>` tag in the page.  The remote server responds with `namedFunction({ ...JSON data })`, which your page runs...without needing an XmlHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

The returned data from the post is used by jquery to determine if the request was successful or not. If it's not the case, an exception will be raised.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your client side code [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9D7U/), however, you probably want to change `"{\"ipaddr\":\"192.168.132.58\"}"` to `{ipaddr:"192.168.132.58"}` since that would be the same as sending a form with a field named `ipaddr` with the value `192.168.132.58`, your own option was sending a field named `{"ipaddr":"192.168.132.58"}` with the empty value.

Good luck.

Comment: I need to send json request. If I do as you wrote I will have post request like this:

ipaddr=192.168.132.58

Instead of json format (what I really need):

{"ipaddr":"192.168.132.58"}

Answer (score 0):

Try and check your server side output for random whitespace, depending on browser that might mess up parsing.

Answer (score 0):

"As far as what they're meant for - the only real technical difference (please correct this post if I'm wrong) is that GET has a much shorter limit to the query string. In practice, GET is meant for when fetching something from the server. A GET call should not cause side effects on the server. POST is when you intend to send something on the server and have it do something with it." ([Difference between jquery.post and jquery.get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375097/difference-between-jquery-post-and-jquery-get))

Have u tried $.get()? It should be faster and is more used to return data from server... Here is some documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Get not working with json format, i.e. I cannot post it in json form.