# Ajax call doesn't work when data is large

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

Hi, I am doing Dynamic web project in Eclipse.

I am using jsp 2.0 and servlet 3.0

In some cases I need to transfer data to server and work on it and come back to same page, so at that time I am in jsp page So I transfer data using ajax and so it will send data without referencing page.

I make the ajax call into loop. It works successfully

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
            $.get('SaveMappingToXML',{objText:selectedTargetObjectsText[li],objVal:selectedTargetObjectsValue[li],rowSrc:mappingSourceFieldValue,rowDesti:mappingTargetFieldValue,rowSrcName:mappingSourceFieldName,rowDestiName:mappingTargetFieldName,sizeOfMapping:rows,objSize:sizeOfSelectedObj,boolVal:li,extID:externalID,refString:mappingReferences},function(res){
                //alert("ajax call successfully.... :)");
            });
```

In above example all element are passed into ajax without index are array of javaScript
so while i am pass 400 element into `mappingReferences` parameter ajax can't call and my web project display me error...

Above ajax call is written into jsp page so I can't debug this page...

So there is any limitation to pass number of arguments into ajax.
I am trying to print that array into `<textarea>` it will display whole array means java Script support 400 element in array so there are any limitation of ajax to pass multiples of elements in to one array...

Comment: URL length is limited, use a POST not a GET

Comment: Also you probably want an asynch AJAX call, unless you have a very good reason to be synch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data length is a prob then you should use $.post here. Please go through to the link [difference of $.post and $.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375097/difference-between-jquery-post-and-jquery-get)

or visit this [link](http://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/jquery/jquery-ajax-get-post-difference/)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: There is also some problem in Post i will put data into hidden text area and get that data in jquery and and pass in $.post call but i will not read properly...

For example 
I passed "Sheet0_Column28_10 CFR Part 73.54,Sheet0_Column169_12 CFR Part 205,Sheet0_Column20_12 CFR Part 229" 
and it send to servlet as "Sheet0_Column28_10+CFR+Part+73.54%2CSheet0_Column169_12+CFR+Part+205%2CSheet0_Column20_12+CFR+Part+229"

Comment: Try to use $.ajax and then send your data through the variable. Like assign your value to a variable var xyz="Sheet0_Column28_10 CFR Part 73.54,Sheet0_Column169_12 CFR Part 205,Sheet0_Column20_12 CFR Part 229"; Actually the problem may be due to the "space" char in you string which is replacing by +, % etc.

Comment: means it wil replace " "(space) with "+"(plush sign) and "," with "%2c"

Comment: hay Naveen i got solution .....
i getting data and separate them by , and put them into array and then I was pass that array into $.post call and at server side i was got that array properly and convert that array into string and use them..
It works...:) 
Thanks for Help..:)

Comment: Thats great :) ...happy coding